# Select rows based on corresponding values from multiple other dataframes

Tags: r

All the ";"-delimited strings in `meth.anno$probeID` match to multiple `geneNames`, as depicted in the corresponding ";"-delimited strings in `meth.anno$geneNames` column.
I retrieved the rows where `meth.anno$probeID` correspond with `rownames(top.cpg.all)`.

For each row of `protein.sig.data` where `protein.sig.data$gene` corresponds with any of the ";"-delimited gene names in `meth.anno.subset$geneNames`, retrieve `meth.anno$probeID` and assign to `protein.sig.data$cpg`. If there are more than one matches per row, separate the `protein.sig.data$cpg` values using ";".

```
meth.asssociated.genes <- meth.anno[meth.anno$probeID %in% rownames(top.cpg.all),]$geneNames
meth.asssociated.genes <- unique(unlist(strsplit(meth.asssociated.genes, ";")))
meth.anno.subset <- meth.anno[rownames(top.genes.all) %in% meth.asssociated.genes,]
protein.sig.data$cpg <- meth.anno.subset[meth.anno.subset$geneNames %in% protein.sig.data$gene,]
```

Traceback:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cpg, value = list(CpG_chrm = c("chr1",  : 
  replacement has 22 rows, data has 137
```

Input:

```
> dput(meth.anno[1:5,5:7])
structure(list(probeID = c("cg13869341", "cg14008030", "cg12045430", 
"cg20826792", "cg00381604"), genesUniq = c("WASH7P", "MIR6859-1;WASH7P", 
"MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P", "MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P", 
"MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P"), geneNames = c("WASH7P", "MIR6859-1;WASH7P", 
"MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P", "MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P", 
"MIR1302-2;MIR1302-2HG;MIR1302-2HG;WASH7P")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(top.cpg.all[1:5,1:2])
structure(list(F.p = c(4.76140440360543e-09, 5.8112687238546e-09, 
1.45285048563695e-08, 1.56278827486753e-08, 1.68970044558462e-08
), F.p.BH = c(0.00108437112133382, 0.00108437112133382, 0.0012611788949808, 
0.0012611788949808, 0.0012611788949808)), row.names = c("cg03575969", 
"cg13869341", "cg21839984", "cg14008030", "cg07728579"), class = "data.frame")

> dput(top.genes.all[1:5,1:2])
structure(list(logFC = c(4.81156925425624, -3.0266509588001, 
5.76347237422447, -1.98486990336191, 3.85842880900616), AveExpr = c(7.09002858792288, 
2.7165174402388, 4.36059483242756, 3.59424523529876, 7.59217318073156
)), row.names = c("WASH7P", "CACNA1H", "SOSTDC1", "ARG2", "KRT7"
), class = "data.frame")

> dput(protein.sig.data[1:5,])
structure(list(logFC = c(-0.339893431264183, -0.644300354116835, 
-0.450280927044743, 0.266095778542012, 0.398774900978989), AveExpr = c(0.0130219667780653, 
-0.177274140145913, -0.0261464054480714, -0.0714618551612862, 
0.0870126659325916), t = c(-14.2096881725535, -11.7060690183211, 
-8.88633263629977, 8.78804398494593, 8.67145791969772), P.Value = c(7.78580560184097e-28, 
8.35255356703595e-22, 5.92827825999527e-15, 1.0164173713975e-14, 
1.92739050312166e-14), adj.P.Val = c(1.68951981559949e-25, 9.062520620234e-20, 
4.28812127472991e-13, 5.51406423983141e-13, 8.36487478354799e-13
), B = c(54.5684483400249, 41.1825860568086, 25.920872288038, 
25.4010532730008, 24.7807278837451), gene = c("YWHAE", "WASH7P", 
"EIF4EBP1", "EIF4EBP1", "ACACA/ACACB")), row.names = c("SHC_pY317", 
"GATA3", "DUSP4", "GSK3ALPHABETA", "PI3KP85"), class = "data.frame")
```